# JavaScript daignostic : $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am facing a weird problem here :

In Firebug I see this error :

> $ is not a function

```
_handleEvent() in pro.js 
 e = load
 var handlers = this.events[e.type], el = $(this);
```

The full function  is defined as follows:

```
_handleEvent : function(e) {
 var returnValue = true;
 e = e || Event._fixEvent(window.event);
var handlers = this.events[e.type], el = $(this);
for (var i in handlers) {
    el.$$handleEvent = handlers[i];
    if (el.$$handleEvent(e) === false) returnValue = false;
}
return returnValue;
}
```

Can you kindly help me out here and figure out why is this error being thrown here. It's not related to jQuery, I guess.

***NOTE :*** It gives this error in IE:

> $(this )  is not a function

Comment: Is jquery actually being loaded?

Comment: I think it is related to jQuery - did you load it in your HTML (**before** loading/running this script)?

Comment: Yes i did so, the full js is loaded there in the jsp.

Comment: If jquery is being loaded then I would say that something else is overwriting $, like $ = null, or jquery is being loaded nonconflict to some other variable name

Comment: Did you try using jQuery instead of $? Does that work?

Comment: OKay, so here, I have used $J = Jquery.noConflict(). Hence this must not over write anything inside the function in the include js. All functionalities are working. but the javascript error has stumped me .

Comment: @BjørnStenfeldt :Thanks a lot man, it seems you were right $j and $ inside the function were conflicting. After changing every $j to jQuery, i was able to get rid of the error. Up flagged. Would have accepted it as an ans , had you answered it. Anyways , thanks again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've either not loaded jQuery correctly or you are executing this code *before* the inclusion of jQuery. Or you might be using jQuery's *noConflict*-mode, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/, in which case you'd need to replace `$()` by `jQuery()`.

Also, make sure you execute this code either at document load or, even better, when jQuery is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your code goes here
});
```